# Number/letters at the top of the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

What do the number/letters mean which appear at the top right of the iOS simulator window?

Comment: What numbers and letters? Be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's iOS build number.  See the `Build` column in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iOS) for examples.